¿Existe alguna forma de detener el hilo?
Quiero mostrar una ventana y que desaparezca después de 1 segundo, intente hacerlo mediante hilos pero se queda el código en root.mainloop() y hasta que cierro la ventana se ejecuta el sleep y la detención del hilo, como manejo los hilos o sería mejor utilizar Toplevel.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import threading

def ventana1():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('ventana 1')
    root.geometry('300x300')
    root.mainloop()

def ventana2():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('ventana 2')
    root.geometry('300x300')
    root.mainloop()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=ventana1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=ventana2)

def hilo1():
    t1.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    #comentado porque da error de runtime porque los hilos solo se inician una vez
    #t1.finish = True

def hilo2():
    t2.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    #comentado porque da error de runtime porque los hilos solo se inician una vez
    #t2.finish = True

def ventana_principal():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('ventana principal')
    root.geometry('300x300')
    btn1 = ttk.Button(root, text='ventana1', command=(hilo1)).pack()
    btn1 = ttk.Button(root, text='ventana2', command=(hilo2)).pack()
    root.mainloop()

t3 = threading.Thread(target=ventana_principal)
t3.start()


La forma adecuada y natural de detener esos hilos sería llamar al método destroy() de las respectivas instancias tkinter.Tk, eso detendría el mainloop y el hilo terminaría su ejecución. No obstante, este no es el camino en este caso, usar hilos no lo es, por varias razones:

Tkinter no es thread-safe como muchos otros framework gráficos. Esto significa que en general debes ejecutar toda la interfaz en el hilo principal del proceso y solo interaccionar directamente con ella desde el mismo.

Normalmente solo debes tener un ciclo de eventos principal ejecutándose por aplicación (Tk.mainloop). No tener esto en cuenta, igual que el punto anterior, puede desencadenar en resultados indeterminados.

time.sleep() es bloqueante, es decir, al ser llamada bloquea la ejecución del hilo hasta que termina, impidiendo que el mainloop de tkinter pueda procesar eventos y actualizar gráficamente la interfaz. Esto no solo queda feo de cara al usuario de la app, sino que, por lo general, no les gusta a los gestores de ventanas, lanzando la típica advertencia "La aplicación X dejó de responder, ¿quieres aplicarle la eutanasia?"...


Para conseguir lo que buscas, usa tkinter.Toplevel en vez de tkinter.Tk para crear ventanas secundarias y el método after() para programar el cierre de las mismas, por ejemplo:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def ventana1(root, time=None):
    ventana = tk.Toplevel(root)
    ventana.title('ventana 1')
    ventana.geometry('300x300')
    return ventana


def ventana2(root, time=None):
    ventana = tk.Toplevel(root)
    ventana.title('ventana 2')
    ventana.geometry('300x300')
    return ventana


def destruir_despues_de(window: tk.Toplevel, time: int) -> None:
    window.after(time * 1000, window.destroy)


def ventana_principal():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('ventana principal')
    root.geometry('300x300')
    ttk.Button(
        root, text='ventana1',
        command=lambda: destruir_despues_de(ventana1(root), 1)
        ).pack()
    ttk.Button(
        root, text='ventana2',
        command=lambda: destruir_despues_de(ventana2(root), 1)
        ).pack()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ventana_principal()


after() simplemente recibe como primer parámetro el tiempo de espera en milisegundos y como segundo el callable a llamar cuando el tiempo pase, en este caso el método Toplevel.destroy(). Por otro lado after() no es bloqueante, mientras se espera el mainloop puede seguir procesando eventos, a diferencia de time.sleep().
